How to Create Bundle Project for .NET Framework
I am attempting to create a project (csproj file) that references a number of packages from a NuGet Package source but doesn't contain any source code itself (or any dlls produced from the empty project contents).
I want to create the project file such that I can produce a dll bundle of the packages that are referenced in the csproj file; I would like it done in this manner so the referenced packages are version controlled.
I have experimented with changing my csproj OutputType to the different options and setting it to Library or Module appears to produce similar behaviour to what I desire. However, it still produces a pdb and either a dll or netmodule file which I would like to avoid if possible.
My example csproj file with a reference to Newtonsoft
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Produces a folder with:

ClassLibrary.dll (I do not want this)
ClassLibrary.pdb (I do not want this)
Newtonsoft.Json.dll (I want this)

I have looked in the

MSBuild reference for .NET SDK projects
Common MSBuild properties

I have also attempted to look through the MSBuild source code without success.

That's not a repository. A csproj file is the project file for a C# binary. It has to produce something. What are you actually trying to do? Create an installer? Publish an application to a specific folder? If you actually want packages and repositories, why not create a NuGet package?

What do you want to do with this "bundle" later?

In any case you can create .proj files that don't target a language, like this root.proj example from the MSBuild repo. It's Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" that makes your project specific to .NET, by including references, tasks and targets meant to create binaries. The MSBuild docs do explain this but mostly show how to work with code projects

Apologies for the wrong terminology, I did mean project. All I really want is for the file to reference some NuGet packages so I can download this bundle of packages and use/store it locally. I'll have a go just using the .proj file

Although @PanagiotisKanavos, if I understand correctly, if I remove the Sdk reference I won't be able to use PackageReference any more to download/reference a package from NuGet

You could define a post build event and deleted the unwanted files.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
       <Exec Command="del $(OutDir)\ClassLibrary.*" />
    </Target>

</Project>


<Exec Command="del $(OutDir)\ClassLibrary.*" />

Run "dotnet restore" to restore the nugget packages:
dotnet restore

Then, run the following "dotnet publish" command to create that "bundle".
dotnet publish --no-build --output ./bundle

Errors may show up, but they can be ignored as they indicate the "publish"couldn't copy the files you didn't intend to include.

Setting my project up in the way you describe and running the dotnet command verbatim still produces the dll file for the project as far as I can tell

You are right, actually, there is no need to that "Compile, Remove" in .csproj. Just make sure your project is cleaned (bin and obj folders removed) and run dotnet restore before the publish. I've updated the Answer.

The closest feature we have is to use a shared project.
It's a special tyype of project that doesn't produce a binary or compiled on its own, but when referenced from other projects all its code is compiled into the referencing project instead.
Have a look at the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022#shared-project-references.
This library of libraries from NuGet could be made into a shared project, so that when you reference it, those other projects automatically import all references. If you later add some code that too would be compiled into each target project. No binary output at all from the central library.

If I'm understand what you've said right, a shared project wouldn't be able to download referenced NuGet packages on its own because it is only used from other projects
